# What is this plant with fluffy white flowers in the Canadian Rockies?

Tags: plants, rocky-mountains, plant-identification

I was hiking in the [Ptolemy Plateau](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/49%C2%B033'35.7%22N+114%C2%B037'02.0%22W/@49.5599285,-114.619422,635m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d49.559925!4d-114.617228?hl=en) in the Canadian Rockies yesterday.

[image]

There were all these plants that looked like something right out of a Dr. Seuss book. What are they?

[image]
[image]

Comment: They reminded me of [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71pdB-OrKZL.jpg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Anemone occidentalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemone_occidentalis)

> Native to far western North America including British Columbia to California and Montana, it is found growing in gravelly soils on slopes and in moist meadows.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's it for sure.